Persons and kid(s) close themselves in a room hiding from an alien-like creature
In this movie, there is a alien-like bald creature (appearance similar to Golum from Lord of the Rings movie). There are some persons including 1 or 2 kids who are scared of it and close themselves in a room. They continue to close other outlets like Windows, roof chimney (not sure) etc. to keep that creature at bay. 
In one scene, somehow that creature comes in and a kid saw it. Then he (or she) suffers mental trauma. 
In the end, they kill that creature by throwing water on it (not fully sure).
This movie is not that old. Maybe released between 7 to 15 years back. This movie was also aired on the Star Movies channel a few times a few years back.

If you could provide more info it will be helpful like if you remember the release year or some more info.

This movie is not that old. Maybe released between 7 to 15 years back. This movie was also aired on Star Movies channel few times few years back.

Sounds like M. Night Shyamalan's Signs from 2002.

Preacher Graham Hess, played by Mel Gibson, has lost his faith in God after his wife dies in a brutal car accident. He along with his son and daughter and his brother Merrill moves into a farmhouse. Crop circles begin to appear in their corn fields which Graham dismisses as mischief by miscreants. After hearing strange noises and watching news coverage on crop circles appearing all over the world, the family begins to suspect of extraterrestrial activities. Now they must stick together and believe, as a family to survive the ordeal and find a way to escape from the clutches of the alien invaders. 

The father and kids run away from the aliens and barricade the house. In the end, they defeat them with a glass of water, which the aliens are sensitive to. Here's the trailer:



